# cant use react - Unexcepted errors

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, runtime-error, runtimeexception

i used react once and it's worked ok.
now i tried to install it again, and it's not working. 
i'll show you my files.
that's webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }
     ]
  }
};
```

that`s .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

and that's package.json

```
`{
   "name": "shopit",
   "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "webpack": "^4.8.1",
      "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "react": "^16.3.2",
      "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
    }
  }
```

i got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
on the first line :

```
import React from 'react';
```

and that`s what my file has. only that file.

someone knows what to do ?

Comment: does this file has `.js` extension?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk yes

Comment: could you post your code somewhere?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk that's my code. only the import line. i dont get what wrong with it..

Comment: post full webpack.config.js

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk i posted it. it's the first code i posted.

Comment: Probably [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html#create-react-app) is best place to begin. `create-react-app` module will do the magic.